# 9-axis motion shield with arduino uno

Tags: arduino

I have previously used an older 9-axis motion shield with Arduino Uno which worked fine but have recently bought a newer version of the 9-axis motion shield and its only returning zeros, not changing angles. It looks like the interrupt and reset pins are different. Does this mean that I can't use the shields any more with the Arduino Uno? I am using the NineAxesMotion library (https://github.com/arduino-org/arduino-library-nine-axes-motion).

Comment: Thanks for your question! I don't know the answer, but I'm guessing you can't use them together. You might be more likely to get other answers if you can provide a model number/type for the uno and the shield. You are also more likely to get an answer if you detail the steps you took to try to find the answer.

Comment: Please provide part numbers, datasheets, wiring diagrams, tables, or explanations, your code in the simplest form that produces your problem, and exact sample output. Those are the things we need to have a chance at helping you.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot give you a definite answer without knowing details on the board versions you're using.

If both versions were sold as Arduino shields they must be compatible to Arduino hardware.

So if you say pins changed between both versions it is just a matter of changing pin numbers in your library code if the hardware is ok.

```
//GPIO pins used for controlling the Sensor
#define RESET_PIN       4       //GPIO to reset the BNO055 (RESET pin has to be HIGH for the BNO055 to operate)

#if defined(__AVR_ATmega32U4__) //Arduino Yun and Leonardo
#define INT_PIN         4       //GPIO to receive the Interrupt from the BNO055 for the Arduino Uno(Interrupt is visible on the INT LED on the Shield)
#elif defined(ARDUINO_ARCH_SAM)   //INT_PIN is the interrupt number not the interrupt pin
#define INT_PIN         2
#elif defined(ARDUINO_ARCH_SAMD)
#define INT_PIN         7
#else
#define INT_PIN         0
#endif
```

https://github.com/arduino-org/arduino-library-nine-axes-motion/blob/2f096fe37199b5f1711d0627b6f04822dc20d4bc/src/NineAxesMotion.h#L95